# what does UUIDs lines means

Tags: java, android, uuid

I get many Bluetooth uuids , I don't know what does this mean and which one I must use to identify the device in my app.

> uuid :00000110a-0000-....
>
> uuid :00000111f-0000-....
>
> uuid :000001112-0000-....

```
    BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); 
    Method getUuidsMethod = null;
    ParcelUuid[] uuids = null;
    try {
        getUuidsMethod = BluetoothAdapter.class.getDeclaredMethod("getUuids", null);
        uuids = (ParcelUuid[]) getUuidsMethod.invoke(adapter, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String s="";
    for (ParcelUuid uuid: uuids) {
        s=s+"UUID: " + uuid.getUuid().toString()+"\n";
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps this service directory can help: the three listed evidently are audio devices: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/service-discovery/.  Also consider `getName` for "friendly" data. Why use reflection - just curious?

Comment: @Andy I can't use name because we can find many devices with the same name, I try in the first the Bluetooth mac address and this the perfect way but that doesn't work and shoes this address 02:00:00:00:00:00 I try every solution but this doesn't work , in the end I see that we can't access to mac address programmatically in new android api levels ,so now I try to identify the Bluetooth of devices who uses the application with UUID but I don't know which one should I use ! (application is a school project for covid-19 to detect contact between users using Bluetooth)